Question about removing old CiviCRM Joomla plugins
I'm prepping to upgrade a Joomla 3.10 website to Joomla 4. This Civi installation was initially set up circa 2010-2011 (last upgraded in Dec 2023, will upgrade as part of this process), so there is some old software hanging around and I don't know if it's needed or can be removed, or if there's an update that I'm missing. These are the plugins:
CiviCRM System Listener v1.0 dated January 2011
CiviCRM User Management v1.0 dated January 2011
I'm guessing the functionality of these plugins is needed, but is there a newer version?
Also installed:
CiviAuthenticate v4.1.1 - I plan to uninstall this prior to the upgrade and then install the newest version.
CiviCRM QuickIcon v 2.5.0 - assuming this is OK and doesn't need an upgrade
